# Change of openid provider url. (google to google apps)

Tags: support, user-accounts, login, google-openid

I am using my blogger account and Google account for Stack Exchange websites.

Now I have switched to Google apps. Can I change/update some way that I can login with new blogger account (I created sample blog) or Google Apps account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, logout of your existing Google Accounts. Head over to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129795/), Click on [My Logins -> Add new login](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?noauto=true&returlUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent) and login with the desired account.